# custom setValueAt method in extended AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So I am working on a DVD Rental System in Java and have run into a view problems.
Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class RentalSystem extends JFrame {

JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenuItem insertMember;
JMenuItem deleteMember;
JMenuItem editMember;
JMenuItem retrieveMember;
JMenuItem insertRelease;
JMenuItem deleteRelease;
JMenuItem editRelease;
JMenuItem retrieveRelease;
JMenu menu;
JMenu menu2;
JComboBox searchMember;
JComboBox searchRelease;
JButton adminButton;
JButton userButton;
JButton existingUser;
JButton newUser;
JTable memberTable; 
JTable releaseTable; 
int existingUserCheck = 1; //0 = existing user, 1 = new user
int adminCheck = 1; //0 = admin, 1 = customer


public RentalSystem()
{
    super("Tape/DVD/Game Rental System");
    setBounds(0,0,1000,500);
    //while(adminCheck == 0)
    {
        display2();
        while(existingUserCheck == 0) {

        }
    }

}
private class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == "insertMember");
        {
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Last Name:");
            String name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Name:");
            String ss = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Social Security Number:");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(ss);
            String email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Email Address:");
            String phoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Phone Number:");
            int b = Integer.parseInt(phoneNumber);
            String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Address:");

            Member member = new Member(name, name2, a, email, b, address);
            //add member to table

        }
        if(e.getSource() == "deleteMember");
        {

        }
        if(e.getSource() == "editMember");
        {

        }
        if(e.getSource() == "retrieveMember");
        {

        }
        if(e.getSource() == "insertRelease");
        {
            String title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this  ,"Enter Title:");
            String type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this  ,"Enter Type(Tape/DVD/Game):");
            String releaseYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this  ,"Enter Year of Release:");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(releaseYear);
            String price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this  ,"Enter Price:");
            int b = Integer.parseInt(price);


            Item item = new Item(title, type, a, b);
            //add item to table

        }
        if(e.getSource() == "deleteRelease");
        {

        }
        if(e.getSource() == "editRelease");
        {

        }
        if(e.getSource() == "retrieveRelease");
        {

        }
      }
    }

private class ComboBoxActionListener implements ActionListener {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String s = (String) searchMember.getSelectedItem();
        String f = (String) searchRelease.getSelectedItem();


            if(s.equals("Last Name")){

            }
            else if(s.equals("First Name")){
            }
            else if(s.equals("Phone Number")){
            }
            else if(s.equals("Member ID")){
            }

            if(f.equals("Title")){

            }
            else if(f.equals("Category")){
            }
            else if(f.equals("Type")){
            }
            else if(f.equals("Rental ID")){

            }


            if(e.getSource() == "Existing User")
            {

            }


    }

}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == adminButton)
        {
            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menu = new JMenu("Members");
            menuBar.add(menu);
            menu2 = new JMenu("Releases");
            menuBar.add(menu2);

            insertMember = new JMenuItem("Insert New Member");
            deleteMember = new JMenuItem("Delete Member");
            editMember = new JMenuItem("Edit Member");
            retrieveMember = new JMenuItem("Retrieve Member");
            menu.add(insertMember);
            menu.add(deleteMember);
            menu.add(editMember);
            menu.add(retrieveMember);
            insertRelease = new JMenuItem("Insert New Release");
            deleteRelease = new JMenuItem("Delete Release");
            editRelease = new JMenuItem("Edit Release");
            retrieveRelease = new JMenuItem("Retrieve Release");
            menu2.add(insertRelease);
            menu2.add(deleteRelease);
            menu2.add(editRelease);
            menu2.add(retrieveRelease);

            JScrollPane c  = new JScrollPane();
            JScrollPane b = new JScrollPane();


            TableModel memberModel = new MemberTableModel();
            TableModel itemModel = new ItemTableModel();
            memberTable = new JTable(memberModel);
            releaseTable = new JTable(itemModel);

            c.add(memberTable);
            c.add(releaseTable);

            String[] searchMemberChoices = {"Search Members By:", "Last Name", "First Name","Phone Number", "Member ID"};
            String[] searchReleaseChoices = {"Search Releases By:", "Title" , "Category", "Type", "Release ID" };
            searchMember = new JComboBox(searchMemberChoices);
            searchRelease = new JComboBox(searchReleaseChoices);


            //add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            //add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(searchMember, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(searchRelease, BorderLayout.EAST);
            add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            setVisible(true);
            setResizable(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            insertMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            deleteMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            editMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            retrieveMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            insertRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            deleteRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            editRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            retrieveRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            searchMember.addActionListener(new ComboBoxActionListener());
            searchRelease.addActionListener(new ComboBoxActionListener());
        }
        if(e.getSource() == userButton)
        {
            adminCheck = 1;

            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menu = new JMenu("Members");
            menuBar.add(menu);
            menu2 = new JMenu("Releases");
            menuBar.add(menu2);


            retrieveMember = new JMenuItem("Retrieve Member");
            menu.add(retrieveMember);
            retrieveRelease = new JMenuItem("Retrieve Release");
            menu2.add(retrieveRelease);

            JScrollPane c  = new JScrollPane();
            JScrollPane b = new JScrollPane();


            TableModel memberModel = new MemberTableModel();
            TableModel itemModel = new ItemTableModel();
            memberTable = new JTable(memberModel);
            releaseTable = new JTable(itemModel);



            c.add(memberTable);
            c.add(releaseTable);


            String[] searchMemberChoices = {"Search Members By:", "Last Name", "First Name","Phone Number", "Member ID"};
            String[] searchReleaseChoices = {"Search Releases By:", "Title" , "Category", "Type", "Release ID" };
            searchMember = new JComboBox(searchMemberChoices);
            searchRelease = new JComboBox(searchReleaseChoices);


            //add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            //add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(searchMember, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(searchRelease, BorderLayout.EAST);
            add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);


            setVisible(true);
            setResizable(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            insertMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            deleteMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            editMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            retrieveMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            insertRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            deleteRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            editRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            retrieveRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            searchMember.addActionListener(new ComboBoxActionListener());
            searchRelease.addActionListener(new ComboBoxActionListener());

        }



        if(e.getSource() == existingUser);
        {

        }
         if(e.getSource() == newUser)
            {
                existingUserCheck = 1;
                JTextField field1 = new JTextField("");
                JTextField field2 = new JTextField("");
                JTextField field3 = new JTextField("");
                JTextField field4 = new JTextField("");
                JTextField field5 = new JTextField("");
                JTextField field6 = new JTextField("");

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                panel.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
                panel.add(field1);
                panel.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
                panel.add(field2);
                panel.add(new JLabel("Social Security #:"));
                panel.add(field3);
                panel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
                panel.add(field4);
                panel.add(new JLabel("Phone Number:"));
                panel.add(field5);
                panel.add(new JLabel("Address"));
                panel.add(field6);
                add(panel);
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Registration",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

                    int ss = Integer.parseInt(field3.getText());
                    int phoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(field5.getText());

                      //memberTable.addMember(field1.getText(),field2.getText(), ss, field4.getText(), phoneNumber, field6.getText());

                }
            }
    }
}
class MemberTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[]  headers = {"Last Name", "First Name", "SS#", "Email", "Phone Number", "Address"};


    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {

        return headers.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void setValueAt(Member a, int rowIndex, int colIndex)
    {

    }

}
class ItemTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void setValueAt()
    {

    }

}
public void display()//displays first screen:admin/user log-in
{
     userButton = new JButton("User");
     adminButton = new JButton("Admin");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    panel.add(userButton);
    panel.add(adminButton);
    add(panel);

    userButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    adminButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void display2()//displays second screen:user log-in / register
{
     existingUser = new JButton("Existing User");
     newUser = new JButton("New User");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    panel.add(newUser);
    panel.add(existingUser);
    add(panel);

    existingUser.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    newUser.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
public void display3() //displays user screen/functionality
{

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new RentalSystem();

}
}
```

Now, Member and Item are just Object classes I made to represent users(Members) and the movies/games(Items).

```
public class Member {
 int status;
 String firstName;
 String lastName;
 int ss;
 String email;
 int phoneNumber;
 String address;
 int memberID;

 public Member()
 {

 }
 public Member(String firstName, String lastName, int ss, String email, int phoneNumber, String address)
 {
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
     this.ss = ss;
     this.email = email;
     this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
     this.address = address;
 }

public void setName(String firstName, String lastName)
 {
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
 }
 public String getName()
 {
     return firstName + " " + lastName;
 }
 public void setSS(int ss)
 {
     this.ss = ss;
 }
 public int getSS()
 {
     return ss;
 }
 public void setEmail(String email)
 {
     this.email = email;
 }
 public String getEmail()
 {
     return email;
 }
 public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber)
 {
     this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
 }
 public int getPhoneNumber()
 {
     return phoneNumber;
 }
 public void setAddress(String address)
 {
     this.address = address;
 }
 public String getAddress()
 {
     return address;
 }
 public void setMemberID(int memberID)
 {
     this.memberID = memberID;
 }
 public int getMemberID()
 {
     return memberID;
 }
 public void setStatus(int status)
 {
     this.status = status;
 }
 public int getStatus()
 {
     return status;
 }
}
```

and

```
public class Item {

String title;
String type;
int releaseYear;
int rentalID;
int price;
boolean inStock;

public Item()
{

}
public Item(String title, String type, int releaseYear, int price)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.type = type;
    this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    this.price = price;

}
public void setTitle(String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public void setReleaseYear(int releaseYear)
{
    this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
}
public int getReleaseYear()
{
    return releaseYear;
}
public void setRentalID(int rentalID)
{
    this.rentalID = rentalID;
}
public int getRentalID()
{
    return rentalID;
}
public void setPrice(int price)
{
    this.price = price;
}
public int getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

}
```

My problem is that I am confused on how to create a custom, overridden 'SetValueAt()' method to populate the JTables with the information from the Members/Items. 
Another problem is all the empty if statements in the Listener classes. I'm not sure how to go about their implementation. If anyone could provide some guidance on any of these issues, or anything else I might have missed, I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Comment: *e.getSource() == "deleteRelease"*, etc... will always evaluate to false, firstly because the getSource() in this context will return the Component on which the event was triggered, and secondly even if it did return a String one should always compare Strings using the equals method

Comment: There are two problems with "if(e.getSource() == "insertMember");", first '==' shouldn't be used to compare the quality of two String values, you should be using String.equals; second, the trailing ";" is short circuiting them, meaning that code immediately after it is been execute regardless of the evaluation of the if statement....

Comment: "public void setValueAt(Member a, int rowIndex, int colIndex)" should be "public void setValueAt(Object a, int rowIndex, int colIndex)" otherwise it will never be called

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah yes, the semicolon's after the if statements were merely a typo. As far as 'setValueAt' is concerned, I'm trying to get it so that:
a.lastName will go in column 1, under a header of "Last Name"

a.firstName will go in column 2, under a header of "First Name"
and so on for all the pertinent data

Comment: setValueAt wants to set the column value, which is represented by the object for the row. Do the first thing you need to do is retrieve the Member for the specified row, then set the property which represents the supplied column

Comment: This "while(existingUserCheck == 0) {" is an incredibility bad idea, as it will cause your UI to hang

Comment: My bad, "if(e.getSource() == "deleteRelease");" is comparing the source of the event (likely a JButton) to a String, so it's never likely to be true...

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean by "retrieve the Member for the specified row"?

Comment: Well, one has to assume, that each row in your table is backed by an instance of Member, and each column is backed by a property of that Member (for a given row)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, yes, that is true. The table needs to be dynamic though, where I can add/delete Members from the table. i.e. there is no fixed number of Members

Comment: Okay, then make it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore all the "interesting" issues with the code and focus on the `TableModel`

A table is a two dimensional matrix of data, spread over a series of rows and column

The `TableModel` provides the contract by which the `JTable` (the view) can interact with the data represented by the `TableModel`...

```
public interface TableModel
{
    public int getRowCount();
    public int getColumnCount();
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex);
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex);
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex);
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex);
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex);
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l);
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l);
}
```

This is important, as you data needs to conform to this contract.

You have a `Member` class which has a series of defined properties, each property represents a possible column value, this makes each instance of `Member` a "row" of data.

The first thing you need to decide is how you are going to manage all the `Member`s.  Since you've stated you need a "dynamic" (or mutable) model, one of the better data structures to use might be `ArrayList`, as it can grow to meet your needs and has fast non-sequential access (you can grab values from it at random points quickly).

```
public class MemberTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] headers = {"Last Name", "First Name", "SS#", "Email", "Phone Number", "Address"};
    private List<Member> members;

    public MemberTableModel() {
        members = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public MemberTableModel(List<Member> members) {
        this();
        this.members.addAll(members);
    }

    public MemberTableModel(Member... members) {
        this(Arrays.asList(members));
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return members.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return headers.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return headers[column];
    }
```

Okay, now we need some we to get the column for a particular row...

```
    protected Member getMemberAt(int row) {
        return members.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Object value = null;
        Member member = getMemberAt(row);
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                // Need getter for last name
                break;
            case 1:
                // Need getter for first name
                break;
            case 2:
                value = member.getSS();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = member.getEmail();
            case 4:
                value = member.getPhoneNumber();
            case 5:
                value = member.getAddress();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Setting the value is pretty much the same process...

```
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
        Member member = getMemberAt(rowIndex);
        switch (colIndex) {
            case 0:
                member.setName(value.toString(), member.getLastName());
                break;
            case 1:
                member.setName(member.getFirstName(), value.toString());
                break;
            case 2:
                if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    member.setSS((Integer) value);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                member.setEmail(value.toString());
                break;
            case 4:
                if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    member.setPhoneNumber((Integer)value);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                member.setAddress(value.toString());
                break;
        }
        fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, colIndex);
    }
}
```

Note, there is no validation in this method, you should be checking to see if the values meet your basic requirements for the data...

But, to make a table editable, you need to override the `isCellEdtiable` method of the model...

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return true;
}
```

Take add or remove members from the model, you need to supply the functionality in your model, for example...

```
public void add(Member member) {
    int size = members.size();
    members.add(member);
    fireTableRowsInserted(size, size);
}

public void remove(Member member) {
    int index = members.indexOf(member);
    if (index > -1) {
        members.remove(member);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
    }
}
```

Take a closer look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Actually you need to implement a lot more than the setValueAt() method. You need to decide on how to store all the data. You need to implement the getValueAt(...) method so the data can be displayed in the table.

Take a look at the `TableDemo.java` code from the Swing tutorial on [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for the basics of creating a custom TableModel. It will show you one way to implement the various methods.

However, that TableModel is not a very good general purpose model since the data is basically hardcoded and you don't have the ability to add new rows of data.

For a better, but more complicated solution take a look at [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). This is a more generic TableModel with far more flexibility. However you will still need to implement a couple of methods for your custom Objects that you want to add to the table. Check out the `JButtonTableModel.java` code found in the blog for an example of the changes required.