# Convert List containing objecs to multidimensional Array

Tags: java, swing, list, multidimensional-array, jtable

I have a ArrayList of objects. Suppose, the object is a class something like this...

```
public class User {

     String userId;
     String name;
     String account_created;
     String date_Of_Birth;

     //setters and getters
  }
```

Iam inserting the data into the list from an external source (like database)

```
List<User> usersList = new UserManager().totalUsersList();
```

I created a new Array for columns

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "Id", "Name", "Account Created", "Date of Birth" };
```

Iam want to send the List data into multidimensional array. Something like ...

```
String[][] usersData = new String[usersList.size()][4];

for (User user : usersList) {
    //usersData = usersData + {"","","",""} ; --> Need to add data into Array while iterating the over the list
}
```

How can i send data from List into the array : `usersData`

Iam sending the data into an array for displaying in a JTable(Swing).

Any Suggestions ...... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a traditional for loop in order to use the indices :

```
for (int i=0; i<usersList.size(); i++) {
    User userTO = usersList.get(i);
    usersData[i] = new String[] {usetTO.getUserID(),...,...,...};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any Suggestions ...... ???

Don't.  Maintain the structure of the data and create a custom `TableModel` (extending from something like `AbstractTableModel`) and use the `List<User>` as the data buffer

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details and [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809509/custom-setvalueat-method-in-extended-abstracttablemodel/29811326#29811326)