# AbstractTableModel with ArrayList and CheckBoxes has setValueAt error

Tags: java, arraylist, abstracttablemodel

I receive a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range error with the AbstractTableModel that I am setting up to display the contents of my ArrayList.    I think it has to do with auto sorting the table.  How do I fix the setAutoRowSorter()?

I have a class 'Account' that holds an ArrayList of another class 'Client'.

The Client class contains information that will be displayed on the table:

The table was created with drag-and-drop.  I also create a quick Account and Client here and make a short list for the table:

```
package presentation;

import domain.Account;
import domain.Client;

public class ClientTable extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Account account = null;
    private ClientAbstractTableModel model = new ClientAbstractTableModel();
    private int selectedRow = -1;

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
        model.setClients(account.getClientList());
    }

    public ClientTable() {
        initComponents();

        myTable.setModel(model);
        myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        myTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Select", "First name", "Last name"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(myTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(187, 187, 187)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(243, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(91, 91, 91)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Account account = new Account();
        Client clientA = new Client(false, "John", "Smith", "New York", "Current");
        Client clientB = new Client(false, "Jane", "Doe", "London", "Prospective");
        account.addClient(clientA);
        account.addClient(clientB);
        ClientTable clientTable = new ClientTable();
        clientTable.setAccount(account);
        clientTable.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable myTable;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And finally here is the AbstractTableModel:

```
package presentation;

import domain.Client;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class ClientAbstractTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Select", "First Name", "Last Name", "City", "Status"};

    private ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setClients(ArrayList<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return clients.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        Object value = null;
        Client client = clients.get(row);

        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                value = client.getSelected();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = client.getFirstName();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = client.getLastName();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = client.getCity();
                break;
            case 4:
                value = client.getStatus();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override    
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        Client client = clients.get(row);
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                if (value instanceof Boolean)
                    client.setSelected((boolean)value);
                break;
            case 1:
                client.setFirstName((String)value);
                break;
            case 2:
                client.setLastName((String)value);
                break;
            case 3:
                client.setCity((String)value);
                break;
            case 4:
                client.setStatus((String)value);
                break;
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I click one of the checkboxes.  After I click one, I am no longer able to click the others, but I can keep clicking the first one I clicked.

In the Exception details I noticed this:

```
at presentation.ClientListTableModel.setValueAt(ClientListTableModel.java:152)
```

which is fireTableCellUpdated(row, column); in the setValueAt() method.

Interestingly, when I remove

```
myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

from the code, the program works without errors.  However, how do I get around this?  I would still like to be able to sort the table by clicking one of the column headers.

For reference, I got some information on how to set up my table from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809509/custom-setvalueat-method-in-extended-abstracttablemodel) and from [this Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Thanks!

EDIT:  Removed some unnecessary code snippets.

Comment: All that code for what use on SO?

Comment: @nullpointer I will cut down on the code to show the relevant portion.  At first I was thinking I should include most of it, but I have narrowed down the issue more.